# Can a interface be ever be extended?

Tags: java

I have a question about java's use of an interface. I initially thought we can only implement interfaces in a given class. But in this code example,

```
public interface InterW {
}
public interface InterX<T> {
}
public class ClassY {
}
public class ClassZ {
}
```

Why is this a valid answer?

```
public class ClassB<T extends InterX<ClassY>> extends ClassZ
implements InterW {
}
```

Can a type parameter extend an interface?

And why is this one wrong?

```
public class ClassE<T implements InterW> extends ClassZ {
}
```

Comment: The `<T extends Xxx>` is a _type bound_; it places a restriction on what `T`s are valid as a type parameter (and correspondingly allows you to do more with such a `T` in the body.)  For purposes of writing type bounds, `extends` and `implements` are merged, since the distinction is not useful and merely gets in the way.  Imagine `extends` in this context means `is a subtype of`, since both extending a class and implementing an interface both express subtyping.

Comment: @BrianGoetz .  So, could I have just replaced extends with implements and the code would still compile? Then why would the second code "`public class ClassE<T implements InterW> extends ClassZ {
 }`" fail to compile? Or is it customary to always write extends to express type bound parameters?

Comment: No, you cannot say "implements" in a type bound.  You just say "extends", which, in this context, means "extends if its a class, implements if its an interface."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a interface be ever be extended?

An interface can  only extends interface .In fact An interface can extends multiple interfaces.

> public interface Interface4 extends Interface1 , Interface2 ,
>   Interface3 {     // methods }

coming back to you second question

```
And why is this one wrong?

`public class ClassE<T implements InterW> extends ClassZ {
 }`
```

As user2615897 mentioned

> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name,
>   followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound .....
>   Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean
>   either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

As per JVM, in context of upper bound whether you use extends or implements both does the same thing. But JVN allows the syntax `extends` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3):

Please see the [Oracle Documentation on Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Particularly -

> To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound ..... **Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).**

Comment: Furthermore, [interfaces can extend other interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html), meaning that the method(s) of the parent interface is (are) inherited to the child interface.

Comment: Referring to the docs.. " Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces)." Doesn't it clearly states that "implements" is used for interfaces? So when I am trying to extend a interface , shouldn't the compiler give out an error?  Or does it mean, when I write extends to declare a bounded type parameter I am just restricting it in some way and  I am not extending a Interface (which is not allowed by java)?

Comment: @ShamveelAhammed exactly. If you use bounded types, there is only the keyword `extends`, which may refer to `extends` when talking about classes and `implements` when talking about interfaces.